# Creating Dynamic Pivot Table Column Names

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have created a pivot table with hard coded column names. The pivot table simply keeps a rolling sum of sales by qty (current month + 11 months back).

It was my first time using the PIVOT function properly and the code works fine.

```
SELECT
    Item_Code_Desc,
    ISNULL([Current],0)     AS [Current],
    ISNULL([1],0)           AS [1],
    ISNULL([2],0)           AS [2],
    ISNULL([3],0)           AS [3],
    ISNULL([4],0)           AS [4],
    ISNULL([5],0)           AS [5],
    ISNULL([6],0)           AS [6],
    ISNULL([7],0)           AS [7],
    ISNULL([8],0)           AS [8],
    ISNULL([9],0)           AS [9],
    ISNULL([10],0)          AS [10],
    ISNULL([11],0)          AS [11]
FROM
    (SELECT
         CONCAT(ST.Code,' - ', ST.Description_1) AS Item_Code_Desc,
         STT.ActualQuantity AS Qty,
         CASE
            WHEN MONTH(STT.TxDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN 'Current'
            WHEN MONTH(STT.TxDate) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())) THEN '1'
            WHEN MONTH(STT.TxDate) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE())) THEN '2'
            WHEN MONTH(STT.TxDate) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())) THEN '3'
            WHEN MONTH(STT.TxDate) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE())) THEN '4'
            WHEN MONTH(STT.TxDate) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -5, GETDATE())) THEN  '5'
            WHEN MONTH(STT.TxDate) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())) THEN '6'
            WHEN MONTH(STT.TxDate) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -7, GETDATE())) THEN '7'
            WHEN MONTH(STT.TxDate) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -8, GETDATE())) THEN '8'
            WHEN MONTH(STT.TxDate) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -9, GETDATE())) THEN   '9'
            WHEN MONTH(STT.TxDate) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -10, GETDATE())) THEN '10'
            WHEN MONTH(STT.TxDate) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -11, GETDATE())) THEN '11'
            ELSE '0'
         END AS [Period]
     FROM 
         _bvSTTransactionsFull AS STT
     INNER JOIN 
         StkItem AS ST ON STT.AccountLink = ST.StockLink
     WHERE 
         STT.TxDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -11, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
         AND STT.Module = 'AR') AS P
PIVOT  
    (SUM(P.Qty)
        FOR P.Period IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[Current])
    ) AS PVT
```

To make the output more dynamic, I wanted to rather show the month and year as the field heading, rather than just the 1,2,3 etc.

To attempt this, I first took out the original CASE, and used the CONCAT function to get the desired result

```
CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH,STT.TxDate),' ',YEAR(STT.TxDate))                     AS [Period],
```

Now that the sub-query was showing the transaction date in the format "mmmm yyyy", I wanted the table to pivot on this. I did start wondering how it was going to do this as I was reaching the end, as the column names are not hard coded anymore.

After trying

```
 PIVOT (
            SUM(P.Qty)
        FOR  CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH,P.TxDate),' ',YEAR(P.TxDate)) 
            ) AS PVT
```

And many other variations I did do some research, and I see this process is slightly more complex than I thought.

I haven't used the STUFF and FOR XML PATH before. I have attempted to convert the above into the examples I have found on the net. But I'm trying in vein as I don't understand the core logic of what I am trying to do.

Please could I have assistance with not only how to get the pivot dynamic, but perhaps some notes to further understand what is happening. Really appreciate some help on this!

*After Attempting*

This is my attempt to get it right:

```
DECLARE
@Cols NVARCHAR(MAX),
@Query NVARCHAR(MAX),
@Module NVARCHAR = 'AR'

 SELECT 
@Cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + 'CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, STT.TxDate),,YEAR(STT.TxDate))' + QUOTENAME(NAME)
                FROM _bvSTTransactionsFull AS STT
                WHERE STT.Module = 'AR'
                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).VALUE('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
 SELECT
@Query = '
SELECT
Item_Code,
Item_Desc,
' +''''+ @Cols + '''''
FROM
 (SELECT
     ST.Code                                                                            AS Item_Code, 
     ST.Description_1                                                                   AS Item_Desc,
     STT.ActualQuantity                                                                 AS Qty,
     CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, STT.TxDate),,YEAR(STT.TxDate))                              AS [Period]
 FROM 
     _bvSTTransactionsFull AS STT
 INNER JOIN 
     StkItem AS ST ON STT.AccountLink = ST.StockLink
 WHERE 
     STT.TxDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -13, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, 
 GETDATE()), 0))
     AND STT.Module = '+ @Module +') AS P
 PIVOT  
(SUM(P.Qty)
    FOR P.Period IN ('+@cols+')
) AS PVT '
PRINT @Query
EXEC (@Query)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Invalid column name 'NAME'.

Where am I off here?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

Comment: Cross tab might also be far easier than the `PIVOT` operator. [Cross Tabs and Pivots](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/cross-tabs-and-pivots-part-1-%E2%80%93-converting-rows-to-columns-1)

Comment: @Gray Meiring, check your email...

Comment: @AaronBertrand  I have added my attempt. Please assist me with where I am going wrong?

Comment: @Birel please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is correct above however, you will not have your columns sorted by the correct date...

The below would cater for that:

```
DECLARE
@Cols1  VARCHAR(MAX),
@Cols2  VARCHAR(MAX),
@Query  VARCHAR(MAX),
@Period VARCHAR(MAX) = -13 ; --/ Select number of months to view back on (excluding current month) \--


declare @tmptbl table (PeriodDate datetime, col1 varchar(100), col2 varchar(100))
insert into @tmptbl (PeriodDate, col1, col2)

SELECT DISTINCT dPeriodDate,'ISNULL('+ QUOTENAME(CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, dPeriodDate),' ',YEAR(dPeriodDate)))+',0) AS' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, dPeriodDate),' ',YEAR(dPeriodDate))) col1
,   QUOTENAME(CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, dPeriodDate),' ',YEAR(dPeriodDate))) col2
                FROM _bvSTTransactionsFull AS S join _etblPeriod p on EOMONTH(s.TxDate) = p.dPeriodDate
                WHERE S.Module = 'AR' AND S.TxDate > = DATEADD(MONTH, -13, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))

SELECT 
@Cols1 = STUFF((SELECT ',' + col1 
                FROM @tmptbl order by PeriodDate
                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')                     --/ allows the first SELECT fields to have the ISNULL function and Alias \--
SELECT
@Cols2 = STUFF((SELECT ',' + col2
                FROM @tmptbl order by PeriodDate
                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')  --/ becasue of the need for ISNULL above, second @Cols needed for the Pivot (pivot cannot have ISNULL in it) \--

SELECT
   @Query =
'SELECT
Item_Code_Desc,
'+@Cols1+'
FROM
(SELECT
     CONCAT(ST.Code,'' - '', ST.Description_1)                                  AS Item_Code_Desc,
     STT.ActualQuantity                                                         AS Qty,
     CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, STT.TxDate),'' '',YEAR(STT.TxDate))                 AS [Period]
 FROM 
     _bvSTTransactionsFull AS STT
 INNER JOIN 
     StkItem AS ST ON STT.AccountLink = ST.StockLink
 WHERE 
     STT.TxDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, '+@Period+', DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
     AND STT.Module = ''AR'') AS P
PIVOT  
(SUM(P.Qty)
    FOR P.Period IN ('+@cols2+')
) AS PVT '

PRINT @Query
EXEC (@Query)
```

I left the changes I made in small caps for you to see the changes...

Comment: Found a flaw, column July has no quantities, but that's due to your period specification - it should be -13 like your columns... edited it in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Solved :)

```
DECLARE
@Cols1  VARCHAR(MAX),
@Cols2  VARCHAR(MAX),
@Query  VARCHAR(MAX),
@Period VARCHAR(MAX) = -12 ; --/ Select number of months to view back on (excluding current month) \--

SELECT 
@Cols1 = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' +'ISNULL('+ QUOTENAME(CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, S.TxDate),' ',YEAR(S.TxDate)))+',0) AS' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, S.TxDate),' ',YEAR(S.TxDate))) 
                FROM _bvSTTransactionsFull AS S
                WHERE S.Module = 'AR' AND S.TxDate > = DATEADD(MONTH, -13, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')                     --/ allows the first SELECT fields to have the ISNULL function and Alias \--
SELECT
@Cols2 = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, S.TxDate),' ',YEAR(S.TxDate)))
                FROM _bvSTTransactionsFull AS S
                WHERE S.Module = 'AR' AND S.TxDate > = DATEADD(MONTH, -13, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')  --/ becasue of the need for ISNULL above, second @Cols needed for the Pivot (pivot cannot have ISNULL in it) \--

SELECT
   @Query =
'SELECT
Item_Code_Desc,
'+@Cols1+'
FROM
(SELECT
     CONCAT(ST.Code,'' - '', ST.Description_1)                                  AS Item_Code_Desc,
     STT.ActualQuantity                                                         AS Qty,
     CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH, STT.TxDate),'' '',YEAR(STT.TxDate))                 AS [Period]
 FROM 
     _bvSTTransactionsFull AS STT
 INNER JOIN 
     StkItem AS ST ON STT.AccountLink = ST.StockLink
 WHERE 
     STT.TxDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, '+@Period+', DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
     AND STT.Module = ''AR'') AS P
PIVOT  
(SUM(P.Qty)
    FOR P.Period IN ('+@cols2+')
) AS PVT '

PRINT @Query
EXEC (@Query)
```